# Android Studio MediaStore Storage не могу получить доступ к папке

Tags: android, kotlin

При попытке скачать и сохранить файл, выкидывает ошибку

```
Primary directory file not allowed for content://media/external/downloads;
allowed directories are [Download]
```

Как можно поправить, может какого-то разрешения нет?

**Код**

```
    private fun shopOrderPrintAgreement() {
        val dialog = context?.let {
            MDialog(it, this@OrderClientFragment).show {
                title(text = "Загрузка")
                message(text = "Подождите, получаем файл")
                cancelable(false)
            }
        }

        val thread = object : Thread() {
            override fun run() {
//                try {
                    val multipartBuilder = MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM)

                    multipartBuilder.addFormDataPart("oid", orderId)

                    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build()

                    val request = Request.Builder()
                        .url(Api.API_URL + "order/shopOrderPrintAgreement")
                        .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer ${Api.token}")
                        .post(multipartBuilder.build())
                        .build()

                    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

                    /**
                     *TODO починить для android 10
                     */
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                        val resolver = context!!.contentResolver
                        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                            put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "agreement_$orderId")
                            put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf")
                            put(MediaStore.DownloadColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "file/Peshkariki")
                        }
                        // MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
                        val uri = resolver.insert(
                            MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            contentValues
                        )

                        if (uri != null) {
                            try {
                                resolver.openOutputStream(uri).use {
                                    it?.let {
                                        val sink = it.sink().buffer()
                                        sink.writeAll(response.body()!!.source())
                                        sink.close()
                                    }
                                }

                                mainActivity.runOnUiThread {
                                    dialog?.dismiss()
                                    try {
                                        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                        intent.setDataAndType(
                                            uri, "application/pdf"
                                        )
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

                                        if (isActivityForIntentAvailable(intent)) {
                                            startActivity(intent)
                                        } else {
                                            val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                            webIntent.setDataAndType(
                                                uri, "text/html"
                                            )
                                            webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                                            webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                                            startActivity(webIntent)
                                        }
                                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                                        e.printStackTrace()
                                        Toast.makeText(
                                            mainActivity,
                                            "Не удалось открыть файл",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                        ).show()
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                Crashlytics.logException(e)
                            }
                        } else {
                            log("OrderClientFragment error with uri == null")
                            Crashlytics.log("OrderClientFragment error with uri == null ")
                        }
                    } else {
                        val storageDir =
                            mainActivity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                        val downloadedFile = File.createTempFile(
                            "agreement_$orderId", /* prefix */
                            ".pdf", /* suffix */
                            storageDir      /* directory */
                        )

                        val sink = downloadedFile.sink().buffer()
                        sink.writeAll(response.body()!!.source())
                        sink.close()

                        mainActivity.runOnUiThread {
                            dialog?.dismiss()
                            try {
                                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                intent.setDataAndType(
                                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                                        mainActivity,
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                                        downloadedFile
                                    ), "application/pdf"
                                )
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

                                if (isActivityForIntentAvailable(intent)) {
                                    startActivity(intent)
                                } else {
                                    val webIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                    webIntent.setDataAndType(
                                        FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                                            mainActivity,
                                            BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                                            downloadedFile
                                        ), "text/html"
                                    )
                                    webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY)
                                    webIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                                    startActivity(webIntent)
                                }
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    mainActivity,
                                    "Не удалось открыть файл",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                        }
                    }

//                } catch (e: Exception) {
////                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread{
////                        Toast.makeText(context, e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
////                    }
//                    swipeRefreshLayout.post { swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing = false }
//                    mainActivity.runOnUiThread(checkInternetConnection)
//                    e.printStackTrace()
//                }
            }
        }
        thread.start()
    }
}
```

Используемые разрешения

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Traceback

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory file not allowed for content://media/external/downloads; allowed directories are [Download]
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureFileColumns(MediaProvider.java:2117)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureUniqueFileColumns(MediaProvider.java:1928)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:2495)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:3254)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:2903)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:309)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:154)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
2020-05-01 19:05:44.698 7774-7992/com.app.peshkariki E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-20
    Process: com.app.peshkariki, PID: 7774
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Primary directory file not allowed for content://media/external/downloads; allowed directories are [Download]
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:481)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1828)
        at com.app.peshkariki.i.i$n0.run(OrderClientFragment.kt:778)
```

778 строчка, это

```
val uri = resolver.insert(
                            MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            contentValues
                        )
```

Comment: а на какую строку указывает ошибка? вы все разрешения запросили для записи? мне кажется тут android studio будет не очень уместно

Comment: на какую строку ошибка указывает? или у вас не показывает?

Comment: @Andred добавил Traceback

Comment: какая версия android у вас используется?

Comment: @Andrew Это на Andrpoid 10

Comment: могу допустить что неправильно пытаетесь получить доступ к папке загрузок, поэтому и эта проблема появилась, в 10 версии много чего убрали при работе с файлами

Comment: @Andrew добавил полностью код

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904485/how-to-save-an-image-in-android-q-using-mediastore - попробуйте, может это вам поможет, проблема такая же

Comment: @Andrew к сожалению нет, у автора почти все то же самое, за исключением что он сохраняет изображение и в другую директорию

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо было заменить на

```
MediaStore.DownloadColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Download/Peshkariki"
```